# Azure Face API: How to resolve the following exception:

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

```
var detectedFace1 = await client.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(request.Image1, true, recognitionModel: recognition04);
```

DetectWithStreamAsync throws the following exception:

> "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"

Why is the exception thrown? Is it possible to get a list of services that are available per resource?

```
var detectedFace1 = await client.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(request.Image1, true, recognitionModel: recognition04);
```

The result should contain an object with a confidence level.

Comment: Duplicate: [Unable to use Azure Face API -Forbidden Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73095624/unable-to-use-azure-face-api-forbidden-error)